# Running script at before halt time

Tags: 14.04, scripts

I know adding script in startup time. Is it possible, adding script in system shutdown time? For an example Whenever a user, shutdown their PC, I want a history -c command will run in the background so that the user's previous worked commands can be erasing in the terminal.
Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/292796/how-to-run-a-script-at-shutdown. However, your 14.04 system uses `upstart` jobs;  once you upgrade to a `systemd` oriented system, you need to do things differently.

Comment: No! i can't able to understand the answer

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://ccm.net/faq/3348-ubuntu-executing-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown#to-execute-a-script-at-shutdown) helps. It is a very simple how-to.

Comment: alternatively to the above ways (which are the proper an clean ones one is supposed to follow) the dirty path would be moving your `/sbin/shutdown` to e.g. `/sbin/shutdown.orig` and replace it with whatever script you like and add the execution of the original shutdown command at the end of said script. I still would not recommend it, but it is a possibility.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute a script upon logout/reboot/shutdown in Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/293312/execute-a-script-upon-logout-reboot-shutdown-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

### To execute a script at shutdown:

1. Put your script in `/etc/rc6.d`
2. Make it executable: `sudo chmod +x K99_script`
3. Notes:

   - The scripts in this directory are executed in alphabetical order.
   - The name of your script must begin with **`K99`** to run at the right time.

For more info please see this [link](http://ccm.net/faq/3348-ubuntu-executing-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown). Hope this helps.

---

Sources:

- [Execute a script upon logout/reboot/shutdown in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293312/execute-a-script-upon-logout-reboot-shutdown-in-ubuntu)